# PHPUnit displays Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

i'm new to unit test and i'm trying to make work a first test !

I get this long error twice:

```
    Fatal Error :Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting in
 C:\wamp\www\portailmg\dev\library\Zend\Test\PHPUnit\ControllerTestCase.php on line 27
    9
```

My bootstrap.php:

```
   <?php

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');



define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../applications/portail'));
define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'development');
define('LIBRARY_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'));
define('TESTS_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));


$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'http://localhost';

$includePaths = array(LIBRARY_PATH, get_include_path());
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $includePaths));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();



Zend_Session::$_unitTestEnabled = true;
Zend_Session::start();
```

my phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit bootstrap="./bootstrap.php" colors="false">
    <testsuite name="MyApp">
        <directory>./application/</directory>
        <directory>./library/</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">../application</directory>
            <directory suffix=".php">../library/Custom</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory suffix=".phtml">../application/views</directory>
                <file>../application/Bootstrap.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./log/coverage" charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true" highlight="false" lowUpperBound="35" highLowerBound="70"/>
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

ControllerTestCase.php

```
<?php
class ControllerTestCase extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public $application;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(
            APPLICATION_ENV,
            APPLICATION_PATH . '\configs\application.ini'
        );

        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'bootstrap');
        parent::setUp();

    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->resetInstance();
        $this->resetRequest();
        $this->resetResponse();

        $this->request->setPost(array());
        $this->request->setQuery(array());
    }

}
?>
```

HomeControllerTest.php

```
<?php

require_once 'application/ControllerTestCase.php';
require_once 'application/controllers/HomeControllerTest.php';

class HomeControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
    public function testLoginAction()
    {
        $this->dispatch('/index/logincra'); //distribuer l'URL à tester en utilisant la méthode dispatch()
        $this->assertController('index'); //spécifie le controller à tester
        $this->assertAction('logincra'); //spécifie l'action à tester




        /*
            Assert against DOM selection; should contain exact number of nodes

            param: string $path CSS selector path
            param: string $count Number of nodes that should match
            param: string $message
            return: void
        */

        $this->assertQueryCount('div.login', 1);
    }

    public function testlogincraAction()
    {
        $this->getRequest()
        ->setMethod('POST')
        ->setPost(array("username" => "example@example.com",
                                       "password" => "password"));
        $this->dispatch('/index/logincra');

        $oLdap = new Mediagong_Ldap_Connect($_POST["username"], $_POST["password"]);

        $this->assertEquals($oLdap->isLoggin(), true);
        $this->assertRedirectTo('/index');
    }
}
```

Arborescence:

```
dev
  applications
      portail  
         configs
         controllers
         layouts
         models
         services
         views
         Bootstrap.php
  htdocs
  ..
  ..
  tests
      application
        controllers
        controllerTestCase.php
      library
      log
      bootstrap.php
      phpunit.xml
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I'm not sure what the purpose of your tearDown method is, since ZF should do all of that itself. Since that's where the error is occurring, does it work if you comment that out?

Comment: thanks but i still have the same error without

Comment: it seems the error comes from my HomeControllerTest.php since when i delete it , the error disappears

Comment: Are you making nested selects on the DB somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you are using Xdebug you might want to increase the `max_nesting_level`. Have a look at the [Xdebug manual](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)

> **xdebug.max_nesting_level**
>
> Type: integer, Default value: 100
>
> Controls the protection mechanism for infinite recursion protection. The value of this setting is the maximum level of nested functions that are allowed before the script will be aborted.

Just add the value to your `php.ini`. I have mine at around 250 depending on the amount of tests you run and their complexity.

Comment: I have this is my php.ini:


; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 250

It was set at 64 before. But i still have the same problem

Comment: it seems the error comes from my HomeControllerTest.php since when i delete it , the error disappears

Comment: did you reload your php.ini after changeing it?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution solved my problem. I just commented the:

"zend_extension = "d:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9.dll"

in php.ini file. This extension was limiting the stack to 100 so I disabled it. The recursive function is now working as anticipated.

Comment: But which recursive function? Hitting the stack limit of 100 normally indicates an infinite loop, so disabling xdebug may have just masked the problem rather than fixing it.